# Latex formulas position

Tags: math-mode, formatting, align

Is there a way to start these formulas the the same vertical "line":
[image]

my latex code:

```
   \begin{equation} Accuracy = \frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}\end{equation}
   \begin{equation} Precision = \frac{TP}{TP+FP}\end{equation}
   \begin{equation} Recall = \frac{TP}{TP+FN}\end{equation}
   \begin{equation} F1 = \frac{2*Precision*Recall}{Precision+Recall}\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat contrary to your stated objective, I would like to recommend that you use the `=` symbols instead of the start of each line as the alignment points. I would also typeset words that are used as variable names in upright letters. Finally, do use `\cdot` rather than `*` to denote multiplication.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % "vn" is short for "variable name"

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\vn{Accuracy}  &= \frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}\\[\jot]
\vn{Precision} &= \frac{TP}{TP+FP}\\[\jot]
\vn{Recall}    &= \frac{TP}{TP+FN}\\[\jot]
F_1            &= \frac{2\cdot\vn{Precision}\cdot\vn{Recall}}%
                       {\vn{Precision}+\vn{Recall}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `[\jot]` here?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - `\jot` (I guess the term is derived from "iota") is a length parameter, with a default value of `3pt`. `\\[\jot]` tells LaTeX to create a line break and to increase the vertical separation by, you guessed it, the value of `\jot`. I did this because I felt that without the adjustment, the rows would look like they're too closely spaced. (See the parallel answer by SandyG for a comparison.)

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `align` environment, which requires the `amsmath` package:

[image]

Note the use of `\mathit` in the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align} 
&\mathit{Accuracy} = \frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}\\
&\mathit{Precision} = \frac{TP}{TP+FP}\\
&\mathit{Recall} = \frac{TP}{TP+FN}\\
&F1 = \frac{2*\mathit{Precision}*\mathit{Recall}}{\mathit{Precision}+\mathit{Recall}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I would also replace `*` with `\cdot`.

Comment: @Mico: I agree, but I thought maybe OP had a specific reason to use `*`.

Comment: `\mathit`, not `\textit`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Fixed. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Thank you also for your help!!